# Rails Rspec Controller Test with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can't get my controller test to work anymore after i added a custom validation to my model.

the model looks like:

## push_entry.rb

```
    belongs_to :push_provider
    has_and_belongs_to_many :push_categories
    validate :require_at_least_one_push_category
    def require_at_least_one_push_category
        if push_category_ids.empty? && push_categories.size < 1
          errors.add(:push_category_ids, I18n.t("errors.messages.require_at_least_one"))
        end
      end
```

and my controller test for #POST looks like:

```
before do
    @push_provider = FactoryGirl.create(:push_provider)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @push_entry = @push_provider.push_entries.build(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:push_entry))
    @push_category = @push_provider.push_categories.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:push_category))
    @push_entry.push_category_ids = [@push_category.id]
    @push_entry.save
  end


describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new push entry for push provider" do
        expect {
          post :create, commit: "Speichern", push_provider_id: @push_provider.id, push_entry: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:push_entry, :push_provider_id => @push_provider.id, :push_category_ids => [@push_category.id])
        }.to change(PushEntry, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
end
```

EDIT #1

my strong parameters in push_entries_controller look this

```
def push_entry_params
    params.require(:push_entry).permit(:title, :entry_text, :style, :image, :url, :published_at, :offer_price, :event_date, :scheduled_push, :push_category_ids, food_offers_attributes: [:id, :dish, :price, :_destroy] )
  end
```

any suggestions?

Comment: show your controller. It might be a strong params issue. Are you allowing `push_category_ids` in your `params.require(X).permit...`

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem myself, i only save one push_category in push_category_ids so i don't need the square brackets in my test. thanks for your help.